# Gradient descent to find closest solution to non-intersecting system of equations

Tags: vector-analysis, approximation, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I'm trying to do gradient descent to approximate the point that minimizes the error for a system of $N+k$ equations with $N$ variables, for large values of $N$ and $k$. We're trying to minimize the value of $||Ax - B||^2$, where $A$ is the coefficient matrix with dimensions $[(N + k), N]$, $x$ is the coordinate vector with $N$ entries, and $B$ is the solution vector with $N + k$ entries. Geometrically, this would be the point that minimizes the total distance from some given $3 + k$ planes, for the case $N = 3$. I've looked into the conjugate gradient method, but can't figure out how to amend the algorithm for the additional $k$ equations. The residual vector has $N + k$ entries, while the guesses and search directions should only have $N$ entries, and conjugate gradient assumes they are the same size. I've thought of finding all $N + k\choose N$ intersections and averaging those points, unsure if that would work or if there's a simpler way.

Comment: How big are $N$ and $k$, and does this need to be done quickly live, or can it take a few seconds or minutes to do one run? Also what language does this need to be implemented in?

Comment: They're both around 100. Time isn't a huge factor, minutes would be fine. Just need a fairly accurate result.

Comment: Conjugate gradient doesn't make sense here as the matrix isn't square, cannot be symmetric, etc. Gradient descent is different. Here you would want to do gradient descent with line search.

Comment: At that scale you can do any number of standard things. In Matlab or Octave just A\b would be fine. Alternately, if you write $A=QR$ as a QR decomposition (obtained by Gram-Schmidt or, ideally, Householder reflection) then you can solve $R^T y = b$ and then $Rx=y$. There's a similar way to do it with the SVD. Any such thing will be faster and more accurate than a from-scratch gradient descent setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain of your problem is $\mathbb{R}^N$, since you want to find $x$. And the range is only $\mathbb{R}$, since you are minimizing $||Ax-B||^2$. Therefore you want to use the G-D to minimize $$ L(x) = ||Ax-B||^2. $$

We want to perform $x_{n+1} = x_n - \gamma_n \nabla L(x_n)$, where $x_{n+1}, x_n,  \nabla L(x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $\gamma_n\in\mathbb{R}$. The value of $k$ does not matter.

To see how to evaluate $\nabla L(x)$ see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3784799/mse-loss-function-and-derivatives/3784826#3784826).

Comment: That is a million dollar question! There is no general good choice for it. The step size has a fancy name: learning rate. There are a lot of articles arguing how to choose $\gamma_n$: https://scholar.google.com.br/scholar?hl=pt-BR&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=learning+rate+gradient+descent&btnG=&oq=learning+rate+gradi.